# Explication de « se consommer »

Tags: vocabulaire

Selon un dictionnaire en ligne, on peut utiliser « se consommer » pour dire que quelque chose se perd, soit une ressource, soit un outil qui peut périr. Le dictionnaire que j’utilisais n’est pas très fiable, donc je vous demande conseil. Pouvez-vous me dire si les énoncés et les phrases que j’ai écrits moi-même utilisent ce mot comme il faut ?

Tout d’abord, le pensais que le mot souligne que quelque chose ne peut pas servir longtemps. On a besoin d’une autre chose qui peut tenir lieu de ce qui s’endommage, ou ce qui ne serait pas comblé. Ceci décrit plutôt une propriété qu’un événement.

> Les semelles de mes souliers se consomment, il faut que j’achète des sabots pour faire ce boulot.
>
> L’huile minérale commence à se consommer, il serait donc sage de trouver une ressource moins épuisable.

Ici, c’est j’essaie de l’utiliser pour décrire le fait que quelque chose s’épuise.

> On a du emporter du blé d’ailleurs après que nos vivres se s’étaient consommés.
>
> Les messagers sont partis sans savoir que leur eau se serait consommé avant l’atteinte de la prochaine auberge.

---

Voici le lien pour la traduction [du français vers le néerlandais](http://www.interglot.com/dictionary/fr/nl/search?q=se+consommer&m=).
Peut-être que la traduction de français en néerlandais est plus utile pour vous. Mon anglais n’est pas bon, mais il me semble que la [traduction en anglais](http://www.interglot.com/dictionary/fr/en/search?q=se+consommer&m=) est
similaire.

Comment: Es-tu sûr que tu ne mélanges pas se consume et se consommer ? Pour ton deuxième exemple au moins je dirais qu'une ressource naturelle se consume, même si je dirais al phrase autrement, mais je n'emploierais pas consommer ici.

Comment: Peux-tu en dire plus sur ta source en ligne ? Un nom, ou mieux, un lien.

Comment: J'ai ajouté le lien sur lequel se reposent mes pensées et les emplois dans les phrases.

Comment: @Laure, Je ne le sais pas. Cette question sert à découvrir l’emploi. J’attends avec espoir une réponse de quelqu’un qui me montre comment d’utiliser le mot adroitement.

Comment: @Laure, _consumer_ quand il n'y a pas combustion est pour moi soit figuratif, soit complètement désuet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

« Se consommer » n'indique pas qu'une chose se perd mais seulement qu'elle est utilisée  et transformée en autre chose, qu'elle sert à alimenter.

Pour insister sur la perte, on dira plutôt « s'user, se raréfier, s'épuiser, etc. »

Voici une réécriture des citations:

« Les semelles de mes souliers <s>se consomment</s>, ... »
  ->
« Les semelles de mes souliers **s'usent**, ... »

Les semelles de mes souliers se consomment peut vouloir dire que qu'on cuisine les semelles pour les manger. :-)

« L’huile minérale commence à se consommer, il serait donc sage de trouver une ressource <s>moins épuisable</s>. » -> « Les réserves de pétrole commencent à se **raréfier**, il serait donc sage de trouver une ressource renouvelable. »

« On a du emporter du blé d’ailleurs <s>après que nos vivres se s’étaient</s> consommés. » -> « On a du importer du blé quand nos réserves ont été **épuisées**. »

« Les messagers sont partis sans savoir que leur eau <s>se serait consommé</s> avant l’atteinte de la prochaine auberge. » -> « Les messagers sont partis sans savoir que **toute** leur eau serait consommée avant qu'ils n'atteignent la prochaine auberge. »

Answer (score 1):

Le se devant le verbe ne s'utilise que pour une action réfléchie. D'autant plus que "se consommer" ne s'utilise pas, contrairement à se consumer qui est une action réfléchie. Par exemple, le bois se consumait plus rapidement que prévu est une action réfléchie du bois sur lui même, on ne peut pas dire le bois se consommait plus rapidement que prévu, ce qui n'aurait aucun sens. En revanche on peut utiliser "se consommer" dans la forme passive, puisqu'il y a inversion du sujet et que consommer est transitif (l'action précisée par le verbe s'effectue sur le complément et non le sujet).
Le CNRTL devrait être ton dictionnaire à présent : http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/consommer